Missing Keyframes in Timeline for Custom Properties (and everything else)
Having a ton of problems with keyframes disappearing using Custom Properties on some bones that I made to control visibility of mouth shapes (other keyframes are invisible as well) however disabling "show only selected" does not make the keyframes appear.
You can see the animation play still and scrubbing through the timeline still allows you to see the visibility of the frames turn on and off. However you cannot edit the frames. It's as if the keyframes exist and don't exist at the same time. It's very weird.
I'll attach a video to show the problem.
https://youtu.be/z5zbi2H1Qdc


It does look weird, your custom properties do act as being animated even though they show blue, not purple green nor orange, so no keyframes or drivers there. It would greatly help if you could share your file so that we can check ourselves what's going on there.

Thanks, I added my file (I think) let me know if that helps.

I see the issue, you are using multiple actions in your animation, the one containing your character's mouth animation is named Armature.001Action, but the one you are currently editing is Action.003.
To change that, two ways:

If it's for a quick change, open the Non-Linear Animation Editor, select the strip named Armature.001Action and press ↹ Tab to enter "tweak" mode. It's a way to temporarily set the active action for quick tweaks. The strip will become green to show it is in tweak mode, and clicking anything else in the NLA editor will exit tweak mode.


If it's for a longer change, open the Dopesheet Editor, set it to Action mode, and load Armature.001Action in the actions dropdown menu. The action will remain active until you either click one of the Push/Stash buttons or select another action in the drop down menu.




Thanks so much! I don't think I'd have ever found this on my own.
